# Visual Studio 2015 -- CPU Usage Profiling Not Working?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I recently upgraded from Visual Studio 2013 Community to Visual Studio 2015 Community.

I've heavily relied on the "CPU Usage" Tool that can be found by doing the following:

1. Click "Debug"
2. Click "Start Diagnostic Tools without Debugging"
3. Click "CPU Usage" Check box
4. Click "Start" button

When the program is complete, it is supposed to show you the functions and the time spent in each. What I get instead is just the name of my executable that I can keep expanding instead of seeing the function names -- It doesn't know the names of the functions.

This worked fine on Visual Studio 2013... I would be able to see the function names and everything worked. I tried creating a new "test" solution/project to see whether this works and I get the same results: No function names.

Does this work for anybody? I also installed VS2015 on a fresh development box and still have no results. **This seems like Microsoft shipped with a Visual Studio bug.**

Note: I'm writing a C++ console application. I've tried this on debug and release builds and ensured that I'm building with debug information.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing.

Comment: There are a fair number of debugger bugs in the VS2015 first release.  Unfortunate but not unexpected for any release before the magical *Update 1*, of which the RC is now available for.

Comment: Updating to Update 1 now. Maybe that will fix it :)

Answer (score 4):

It's in the [Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 release notes](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update1-vs.aspx), so I suspect it was broken in the initial release:

> Profile your CPU Usage while debugging
>
> Now, you can get a detailed per-function profile of your CPU Usage while you are debugging. You can turn CPU Profiling on and off while debugging and view the results when you are in a break state, which allows you to view a per-function breakdown of CPU Usage of code that executed between breakpoints and during steps. (To use this functionality, open the Diagnostic Tools window (Debug -> Diagnostic Tools), switch to the CPU tab, and then click the "CPU Profiling" button.)

Answer (score 0):

I have also noticed this, but if you use that little search box (top right corner of the results area) and try typing in either the name of the function you're looking for or part of the name and it will expand everything (there's usually a lot to expand) and highlight the function you're looking for.  Its the only way I've been able to profile specific functions.